# Windows Batch read a file, parse and output

Tags: batch-file

I'm 90% of the way there on a Windows Batch file. 
It takes 2 input parameters, input and output files. 
It then reads in the input file, and substrings certain lines into arrays (Well line 2 onwards). 
Then we come to a loop for outputting. 
With delayed expansion on my counter for going through the array doesn't update unless I use !counter2!, %counter2% doesn't work.

Using !arrayname[!counter2!]! doesn't work.

Here is the code as it stands.

```
@Echo off
if [%1] == [] goto usage
if [%2] == [] goto usage

echo start time : %time%>logfile.log
set input_file=%1
set output_file=%2
if exist %output_file% del %output_file%
Echo Start reading %input_file%>> logfile.log
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a counter=1

for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type %input_file%') DO (
  ::echo !counter!
  if "!counter!"=="1" set header=%%a
  if not "!counter!"=="1" (
  set data[!counter!]=%%a
  set line=%%a
  set jobnumber[!counter!]=!line:~0,7!
  set docnumber[!counter!]=!line:~7,5!
  set pagecount[!counter!]=!line:~12,2!
  set customernumber[!counter!]=!line:~14,20!
  set presort[!counter!]=0000
  set postcode[!counter!]=0000
  set inserts[!counter!]=!line:~36,11!
  set filler[!counter!]=000000
  set address[!counter!]=!line:~58,350!
  set filler2[!counter!]="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "
  set endline[!counter!]=X
)
  set /a counter=counter+1
)
Echo Start writing %output_file%>> logfile.log

for /L %%G in (2,1,%counter%) DO (
  set counter2=%%G
  echo !counter2!
  echo !jobnumber[%counter2%]!!docnumber[%counter2%]!!pagecount[%counter2%]!!customernumber[%counter2%]!!presort[%counter2%]!!postcode[%counter2%]!!inserts[%counter2%]!!filler[%counter2%]!!address[%counter2%]!!filler2[%counter2%]!!endline[%counter2%]!>>%output_file%
)

echo end time : %time%>>logfile.log
pause
goto :eof

:usage
echo Usage: blah.bat input_filename output_filename
pause
goto :eof
```

It is the echo !jobnumber[%counter2%]! where things are not being resolved. 
The echo !counter2! works fine.

Before you ask, Yes I know this could be done better and easier in C# or another programming language, However I am tasked with doing it in a windows batch file.

Thanks in advance for any help provided. 
Tel

Comment: but you can use directly `!jobnumber[%%G]!` ...

Comment: Ahhh Right. In my first loop that didn't work, but thats because counter is changing. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
for /L %%G in (2,1,%counter%) DO (
  set counter2=%%G
  echo !counter2!
  echo !jobnumber[%%G]!!docnumber[%%G]!!pagecount[%%G]!!customernumber[%%G]!!presort[%%G]!!postcode[%%G]!!inserts[%%G]!!filler[%%G]!!address[%%G]!!filler2[%%G]!!endline[%%G]!>>%output_file%
)
```

You are not changing the value of the `coutner2` so you don't need it and you can directly use `%%G`.

Though if you need changes in `counter2` you'll have to wrap it again in for loop and to use its tokens.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.